Computer has been acting strange InProcServer32 with antialiasing
I’ve had crazy high internet usage and my computer is acting strange… not updating, randomly turning on, passwords changed, locked out of admin account, etc.
I found DX2D anti-aliasing and InProcServer32 under hkey_class_root\clsid… is this normal?
How do I get rid of whatever is messing with my device?

This question is similar to: How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hmmm... Just a random guess (sarcasm intended)... no THIS IS NOT NORMAL!!! A computer does not change it's password randomly, nor does it registry edit strange values!
